Freeswitch check if message received is "INFO" in dialplan
I'm trying to check in the dialplan if an incoming message to freeswitch is an "INFO" message.  If the condition is true i need to execute a local script.
Is possible to do this?.   Maybe something like:
<condition field="${incoming-message}" expression="INFO">
             do something..
</condition>

Thanks!
Ricardo

I finally found a way to solve this request.  I couldn't do it through the dialplan. Instead i created a little script in php which connects to the event socket.  There i was able to capture the RECV_INFO event, and from there do almost everythig i needed....
Hope this help someone who's looking the same results.
